# My Angular website run on sub-domain is slower than root domain with same docker image

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, subdomain

**My Angular website run on sub-domain is slower than root domain with same docker image**
So, I have an Angular 11 Docker image, I have run 2 container at mydomain.com and beta.mydomain.com
Basically, client-side render with the same speed.
But in server-side, the client-side return in 2-3 seconds, and beta.mydomain.com in 9 to 10 seconds.
They are all same image, same api calling, same server, same docker-compose.yml . I have no idea for that.
If anybody have some ideas, please teach me. Thank you.

I have using same docker image, same api calling, same server, same docker-compose.yml